# Regarding the keycloak url not being displayed through react app sign in for a client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, web-development-server, graphiql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Oku.png)

```
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\KeycloakApp\login-app\node_modules\@react-keycloak\web\lib\@react-keycloak\web\withKeycloak.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\KeycloakApp\login-app\node_modules\@react-keycloak\web\lib\@react-keycloak\web\withKeycloak.tsx'
```

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
  const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/",
    realm: "Restapi-app",
    clientId: "react-auth"
```

});
export default keycloak;